# Im trying to create an excel file....but while running on the server the following error comes

Tags: c#, asp.net

Microsoft Office Excel cannot open or save any more documents because there is not enough available memory or disk space.

To free disk space, delete files you no longer need from the disk you are saving to.

any idea why???

Comment: Did you check the amount of RAM used? And what about virtual memory?

Answer (score 0):

Try checking if you have enought diskspace on your Harddrive. Also open task manager and close and open EXCEL.EXE tasks that are running.

Answer (score 0):

Add following attribute in machine.config

```
<processModel userName="System" password="AutoGenerate"/>.
```

**Updated**

Follow following steps

1. Go to run type **dcomcnfg**
2. Click >Component services >Computers >My Computer>Dcom config> and select Microsoft Excel Application>
3. Right Click on Microsot Excel Application>Properties>Give Asp.net Permissions
4. Select Identity table >Select interactive user >select ok

Also check out [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757/en-us) link for more details

Comment: Can you give more details on why?

Comment: @Nayan:When you run the ASP.NET application in VS.NET  build-in web development server, the ASP.NET running account is the current logon windows account (Probably it is local administrator). After publishing to the IIS, the web application is running under ASPNET account.